# Detecting and removing wrong timestamps from dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, time, rows

next try here :

I got a `data.frame` with 5 million rows and a column called "arrival time", which has the following format

```
"11:30:00"
"12:30:00"
"13:30:00"
```

and so on.

At some places in the `data.frame`, it contains faulty entries like this one:

```
"111:4:00"
```

The length of both is the same (8). How can I remove these faulty entries fast?
I guess it has to look for a certain type of string and only allow that :

```
[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

Please help!

Comment: Try with `grep("^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}", vec, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the faulty entries using `strptime`:

```
# Sample data.frame 
df <- data.frame(
   Date=c("11:30:00",
     "12:30:00",
     "13:30:00",
     "111:4:00")
)
# Remove the entries which are not following the date format
df[is.na(strptime(df$Date,format="%H:%M:%S")),]
```

Output:

```
[1] 111:4:00
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`

```
grep("^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$", vec, value = TRUE)
#[1] "11:30:00" "12:30:00" "13:30:00"
```

---

Or another option is `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
vec[!is.na(times(vec))]
#[1] "11:30:00" "12:30:00" "13:30:00"
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("11:30:00", "12:30:00", "13:30:00",  "111:4:00")
```